# Is possible to have the console active only on certain times after compiling the py to exe using pyinstaller or anything else?

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

I’m building a program in python that will copy large files using robocopy. Since the gui freezes while the copy is done i only have two options: 
1. Learn how to do multithreading and design the gui to show the progress and not freeze.
2. Keep the console on after compiling with pyinstaller as an alternative to show robocopy progress while the gui freezes.

I am open to doing multithreading but i’m a beginner and is pretty hard to understand how to make another subprocess for robocopy and from there extract the progress into a label from gui. The option i thought about is to have the cmd console active only while the copy is done. Is it possible? The scenario will be like this:

1. Open the program (the console will be hidden)
2. Press the copy button (console pops up and shows the copy progress while the gui freezes)
3. After the copy is done hide the console again

As i said above. I’m not totally excluding adding multithreading but for that i will need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! If PyQt5 is ok for you then I have an example of threading realize in very simple clock(https://github.com/dotslines/simplle_lcdDisplay_PyQt5_clock/blob/master/clock.py), my example is primitive but hope it will help to understand how does it work.
If you have your project on GIThub then may be I could try to help you.

Comment: Sadly i used tkinter not PyQt5. I don't have my project on github but here's the function that is copying the folder:


`def copy_build_button():        #instructions for what to do when the button is pressed




  if selection_platf<11:
    call(["robocopy", src , dest , r"/XF", 'BT V_SyncPackage.zip' , "/S"])


  else:                 #for linux 
    call(["robocopy", src , drst, "/S"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, should be working, please let me know if something wrong:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import subprocess
import threading


main = tk.Tk()
main.title('Title')
frame_main = tk.Frame(main)
frame_main.grid(columnspan=1)

src = 'D:/path/to/the/folder'
dest = 'D:/path/to/the/folder2'
selection_platf = len(os.name)


def copy_build_button():
    if selection_platf < 11:
        subprocess.call(["robocopy", src, dest, r"/XF", 'BT V_SyncPackage.zip', "/S"])
    else: #for linux
        subprocess.call(["robocopy", src, dest, "/S"])


def copy_thread():
    thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=copy_build_button)
    thread_1.start()


button_main1 = tk.Button(frame_main, text="copy_build_button", width=50, height=5, fg="green", command=copy_thread)
button_main1.grid(column=0, sticky='N'+'S'+'E'+'W')

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works!! You are the best!! Didn't thought it will be this simple after all the videos i watched with people doing multithreading. Now, is there any way to display in a label the copy progress that robocopy is printing in the console?

Comment: Regarding the threading process. I get this error if i try to copy another item without restarting the program:    

raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Comment: I've made some changes for RunTime Error, so now it should be working without this error. As for progressBar, I've tried to create it but unfortunetly without any effect, need somebody more experienced. Sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. Now it works. I think i will just keep the console for the progress output.